# Finding the Thévenin Equivalent without seeing circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, thevenin

So I have this task:

Per-Erik connected a load resistor RL to a battery rated to be 9V. He measured the voltage (VL) over the load resistor for different values of RL. The measured data is shown in the table below.

[image]

Determine the Thevenin equivalent of the 9V battery

So my specific question is, how I am supposed to know how the circuit looks like? All I know is that there is a voltage source and a load resistor.

I know how to find the Thévenin Equivalent, so my problem is not that.

Comment: What is "Per-Erik"? The rest appears easy.

Comment: The Thevenin circuit always looks the same, regardless of what the real circuit is. So if you know "how to find the Thevenin Equivalent" then you have everything you need.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. We expect you to do a significant amount of work and ask a specific question.

Comment: I think I was pretty specific on what I wanted to understand. I don't think it is wrong to ask just how I'm supposed to know how the circuit should look like? Like I said, I don't have a problem solving the Thévenin Equivalent.

Comment: You aren't asked what the circuit looks like. You're asked what is it's Thevenin equivalent. But you say you already know how to find that. So you're done, you've already solved the problem you were asked to solve.

Comment: But this "circuit" is supposed to consist of one load resistor and a voltage source. How am I supposed to find the Vth and Rth when there is only two sources. That is what's making me confused.

Comment: Hint: This question is not **just** about a Thévenin circuit. It also expects you to  know how a real battery behaves and why it behaves that way. So why does a 9V battery output only 7.28 volts?

Comment: @Vetenskap, Now I'm confused, first you said you know how to find the Thevenin equivalent. Now you're saying you don't. What is the method that you know for finding the Thevenin equivalent and why do you think it doesn't apply here?

Comment: Also, why do you say there are "two sources"? There's one source inside the Thevenin model, and two resistors. One resistor is inside the Thevenin model and one is the load you (or Per-Erik) connected outside.

Comment: Finally, a hint: if you know a resistor's value and you know the voltage across it, you can find the current through it.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the circuit. Calculate the load current for each RL.

Next, use KVL. You have two unknown variables (Vth & Rth). You have 5 data points, you only need 2 to get two equations. Two equations, two unknowns.

Note that if the 5 data points don't form a straight line on a V-I curve, then there is more than one answer depending on which data points that you use. Normally, the end data points give the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question tells you exactly what the circuit looks like. The circuit consists of a nominal 9V battery with a resistor connected between the positive and negative terminals. That's the whole circuit.

The Thevenin Equivalent Circuit is just an ideal voltage source and an ideal resistor. If you know how to find the Thevenin Equivalent, then you know how to find the values of those elements.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the Thevenin equivalent is that no matter what circuit you have, if it's made up from voltage (or current) sources and resistors and you have only two points to connect to it at, then you can model it with the exact same equivalent circuit.

It doesn't matter if the circuit is one cell, or 37 cells and 135 resistors in a complicated arrangement. In any case you can model it with the Thevenin equivalent consisting of only a voltage source and resistor in series.

Now if you take that equivalent model and connect different load resistors to it, you'll find that by reducing the load resistance, you also decrease the voltage seen at the terminals. This exact behavior is shown in the data you were asked to work with.

So, go ahead. Don't worry about what's inside the black box. You say you know how to find the Thevenin equivalent model. So do that. It's all that the question asks you to do.

Comment: You change one small thing and they freak out. It just shows they don't learn to understand rather they just memorize! So sad